# FFmpeg error code 254

Tags: java, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I try to get file informations via ffprobe in a java-application.

I am using the following command:

> /usr/bin/ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams TESTVIDEOPATH

Running that command in bash, it works like a charm: It returns the JSON-String and error code is "0".
Running that command in Java results in error code "254" and result is:

> {\n}\n

When I modify the command, so that ffprobe accepts a stream as input:

> /usr/bin/ffprobe -v quiet -i - -print_format json -show_format -show_streams

it works in both bash and Java.

In Java the following is used:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
this.process = processBuilder.start();
this.process.waitFor();
int exitCode = this.process.exitValue();
this.outputOfProcess = this.process.getInputStream();
```

Can anyone tell me what the error code 254 means? I couldn't find anything about it.

Edit: ffmpeg version 0.10.7-6:0.10.7-0jon1~quantal is used

Comment: You should try running it without `-v quiet` and see what it says about why it's not working.  A space in the path to TESTVIDEOPATH perhaps?

Comment: @blahdiblah Removing -v quiet gave me a message, that the file could not be found. Reason: TESTVIDEOPATH was given in Java with >"< to get spaces in the filepath to work. In the bash it worked with >"<, but Java applied extra escaped >"<. I did a workaround to pass the TESTVIDEOPATH without >"< and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code 254 for FFprobe means: File not found.

Thanks to blahdiblah for the tip removing `-v quiet` from the command.

The TESTVIDEOPATH was given with `"` at the beginning and end to get spaces in the pathname to work. When executing it, Java excaped these `"` and put some extra around.